# spring boot, flyway - how to write dialect independent (jdbc) sql query?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, flyway

I want to write JDBC(database independent) flyway migrations in spring boot maven project.
Flyway documentation mentions that it uses JDBC connection to run the migrations, but it seems that it allows using both the syntax of the concrete dialect mixed with JDBC syntax...?

Consider this:

```
create table "user" (
    id serial primary key,
    nick varchar unique not null,
    password varchar not null,
    motto varchar,
    created_on timestamp with time zone not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

This migration runs successfully but isn't the syntax Postgres dependant?

I tried to make `id` column to be `bigint not null primary key` and it runs OK too.
I  am also having hard time figuring out about `timestamp` type - aren't the `with time zone` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` parts also Postgres specific?

**So, my questions:**

- do flyway migrations run **fully** in JDBC "dialect"?
- If so, does that mean that any migration which runs successfully is dialect independent?
- Are there any JDBC specific data types and functions?

Comment: I switched to sql server just for the test and the migration indeed seems to be dialect dependant. In sql server, it does not know "serial" data type as well as "with time zone" and timestamp default value throws this: "Defaults cannot be created on columns of data type timestamp. Table 'user', column 'created_on'." "Timestamp" is probably different data type there. So my question stands.

Comment: If you want a tool that can manage multiple database from the same migration script, you'll probably need to use Liquibase and its XML format. JDBC is not an abstraction layer for SQL, but for the communication protocol. The SQL sent through JDBC is still "native" (DBMS dependent) SQL

Comment: Well, now I am not sure about migrations being independent in general. Does liquidbase guarantee that the query is dialect independent? Why does flyway state this as well but does not work this way? Can you clarify or provide more information?

Comment: If you stick with the XML format, then it's pretty much DBMS independent, yes. But you can still generate DBMS dependent stuff if you need to (e.g. when using non-standard data types). I can't understand Flyway claims to be DBMS independent. They only support plain SQL scripts which are always going to be DBMS dependent for anything non-trivial

Comment: Okay, thanks very much. Please, post this as the answer. It would be awesome if you could elaborate more on what is flyway, JDBC and why it doesn't translate the SQL; and why liquidbase does; as there may be more people wondering... :)

Comment: My JDBC confusion comes from this article: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3388036/what-is-jdbc-introduction-to-java-database-connectivity.html It says things like "JDBC is the common API that your application code interacts with. Beneath that is the JDBC-compliant driver for the database you are using." and "A JDBC driver is a class that implements the JDBC API for a specific database.". If flyway uses JDBC, shouldn't it automatically use JDBC manager and concrete db driver (which I have in pom.xml as dependency)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As far as I know Flyway doesn't claim to be database independent. In fact their [documentation page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/) says _"Migrations can be written in SQL (database-specific syntax (such as PL/SQL, T-SQL, ...)"_. You can however combine 'generic' migrations with database specific migrations and at runtime select the 'right' combination of migrations to use.